# How to find message ID of an email in Outlook with javamail

Tags: java, spring, outlook, jakarta-mail

i'm using javamail to fetch emails in outlook  for my java app and i don't know how to get the message id (as u see in the pic below)  with javamail

[message-id-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw34m.png)

Comment: Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching on different documentation of java mail i found the solution below:
((MimeMessage) message).getMessageID()
it helps to get the message id